# Why isn't Blackbeard dead?

Tags: one-piece

It's a known fact that Blackbeard had a fight with Magellan.
Magellan poisoned Blackbeard and all of his crew.

They're seen covered in Magellan's poison after the scene below.

Why aren't they dead and how did they (also) escaped Impel Down?[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's because Shiryu gave them the antidote before joining their crew.

[image]

It happen in episode 452 of the anime and in chapter [549](http://www.mangapanda.com/103-2656-1/one-piece/chapter-549.html) of the manga.

Comment: Also they escaped during the mass confusion by escaped prisoners.  Magellan only managed to capture some of them. Many of the level 5 and 6s are still missing.

Comment: is this seen? Shiryu giving him a "bottle" of antidote or something like that or it's just mentioned?

Comment: word antidote is specifically used

Comment: The bottle is shown at minute 1:27 of episode 452